# Name for proof by logical equivalence

Tags: proof-writing

A discussion on ELU stackexchange has led to the question of whether there is a name for the style of proof in which you start with the proposition to be proven and then proceed via a chain of logically equivalent paraphrases to—in the example below—a definitional criterion (though it could equally be to something obviously true or previously proven).

For instance, you can prove that, if $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms (with the domain of $g$ subsuming the range of $f$), then $g ∘ f$ too is an isomorphism as follows:

> $g ∘ f(x) = g ∘ f(y)$
>
> $⇔ g(f(x)) = g(f(y))$
>
> $⇔ f(x) = f(y)$ — given that $g$ an isomorphism
>
> $⇔ x = y$ — given that $f$ is an isomorphism

This is such a basic method of proof that I can easily imagine that it doesn’t have a name.  But does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually called something like "proof by inspection" or "proof by direct calculation".

Comment: Yes, I would call that a "direct proof"

Comment: My memory of proof by inspection was more along the lines of _The solutions to this equation are 1 and 3_ and you'd substitute those values and check that the equation equated.  But I followed up on _direct proof_ (on wikipedia) and that seems spot on.